# How to add border for pong game so ball bounces off of a black line on Lua

Tags: lua, drawing, love2d, pong

I am trying to get a border around my pong game while still being able to play the game properly. I have no idea how to do this. can someone help me?

Here is my code

Main

```
push = require 'push'


Class = require 'class'


require 'Paddle'


require 'Ball'
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 0, 0, 0, 255 )
end
-- size of our actual window
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

-- size we're trying to emulate with push
VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 432
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 243

-- paddle movement speed
PADDLE_SPEED = 235
--[[
    Called just once at the beginning of the game; used to set up
    game objects, variables, etc. and prepare the game world.
]]
function love.load()
    -- set love's default filter to "nearest-neighbor", which essentially
    -- means there will be no filtering of pixels (blurriness), which is
    -- important for a nice crisp, 2D look
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')

    -- set the title of our application window
    love.window.setTitle('Pong')

    -- seed the RNG so that calls to random are always random
    math.randomseed(os.time())

    -- initialize our nice-looking retro text fonts
    smallFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 8)
    largeFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 16)
    scoreFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 32)
    love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)

    -- set up our sound effects; later, we can just index this table and
    -- call each entry's `play` method
    sounds = {
        ['paddle_hit'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/paddle_hit.wav', 'static'),
        ['score'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/score.wav', 'static'),
        ['wall_hit'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/wall_hit.wav', 'static')
    }
    
    -- initialize our virtual resolution, which will be rendered within our
    -- actual window no matter its dimensions
    push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, {
        fullscreen = false,
        resizable = true,
        vsync = true,
        canvas = false
    })

    -- initialize our player paddles; make them global so that they can be
    -- detected by other functions and modules
    player1 = Paddle(10, 30, 5, 20)
    player2 = Paddle(VIRTUAL_WIDTH - 10, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 30, 5, 20)

    -- place a ball in the middle of the screen
    ball = Ball(VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - 2, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 2, 4, 4)

    -- initialize score variables
    player1Score = 0
    player2Score = 0

    -- either going to be 1 or 2; whomever is scored on gets to serve the
    -- following turn
    servingPlayer = 1

    -- player who won the game; not set to a proper value until we reach
    -- that state in the game
    winningPlayer = 0

    gameState = 'start'
end


function love.resize(w, h)
    push:resize(w, h)
end


function love.update(dt)
    if gameState == 'serve' then
 
        ball.dy = math.random(-50, 50)
        if servingPlayer == 1 then
            ball.dx = math.random(140, 200)
        else
            ball.dx = -math.random(140, 200)
        end
    elseif gameState == 'play' then

        if ball:collides(player1) then
            ball.dx = -ball.dx * 1.03
            ball.x = player1.x + 5

            -- keep velocity going in the same direction, but randomize it
            if ball.dy < 0 then
                ball.dy = -math.random(10, 150)
            else
                ball.dy = math.random(10, 150)
            end

            sounds['paddle_hit']:play()
        end
        if ball:collides(player2) then
            ball.dx = -ball.dx * 1.03
            ball.x = player2.x - 4

            -- keep velocity going in the same direction, but randomize it
            if ball.dy < 0 then
                ball.dy = -math.random(10, 150)
            else
                ball.dy = math.random(10, 150)
            end

            sounds['paddle_hit']:play()
        end

        -- detect upper and lower screen boundary collision, playing a sound
        -- effect and reversing dy if true
        if ball.y <= 0 then
            ball.y = 0
            ball.dy = -ball.dy
            sounds['wall_hit']:play()
        end

        -- -4 to account for the ball's size
        if ball.y >= VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 4 then
            ball.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - 4
            ball.dy = -ball.dy
            sounds['wall_hit']:play()
        end

        -- if we reach the left or right edge of the screen, go back to serve
        -- and update the score and serving player
        if ball.x < 0 then
            servingPlayer = 1
            player2Score = player2Score + 1
            sounds['score']:play()

            -- if we've reached a score of 10, the game is over; set the
            -- state to done so we can show the victory message
            if player2Score == 10 then
                winningPlayer = 2
                gameState = 'done'
            else
                gameState = 'serve'
                -- places the ball in the middle of the screen, no velocity
                ball:reset()
            end
        end

        if ball.x > VIRTUAL_WIDTH then
            servingPlayer = 2
            player1Score = player1Score + 1
            sounds['score']:play()

            if player1Score == 10 then
                winningPlayer = 1
                gameState = 'done'
            else
                gameState = 'serve'
                ball:reset()
            end
        end
    end

  
    if love.keyboard.isDown('w') then
        player1.dy = -PADDLE_SPEED
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('s') then
        player1.dy = PADDLE_SPEED
    else
        player1.dy = 0
    end

    -- player 2
    if love.keyboard.isDown('up') then
        player2.dy = -PADDLE_SPEED
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('down') then
        player2.dy = PADDLE_SPEED
    else
        player2.dy = 0
    end


    if gameState == 'play' then
        ball:update(dt)
    end

    player1:update(dt)
    player2:update(dt)
end


function love.keypressed(key)
    -- `key` will be whatever key this callback detected as pressed
    if key == 'escape' then
        -- the function LÖVE2D uses to quit the application
        love.event.quit()
    -- if we press enter during either the start or serve phase, it should
    -- transition to the next appropriate state
    elseif key == 'enter' or key == 'return' then
        if gameState == 'start' then
            gameState = 'serve'
        elseif gameState == 'serve' then
            gameState = 'play'
        elseif gameState == 'done' then
            -- game is simply in a restart phase here, but will set the serving
            -- player to the opponent of whomever won for fairness!
            gameState = 'serve'

            ball:reset()

            -- reset scores to 0
            player1Score = 0
            player2Score = 0

            -- decide serving player as the opposite of who won
            if winningPlayer == 1 then
                servingPlayer = 2
            else
                servingPlayer = 1
            end
        end
    end
end

--[[
    Called each frame after update; is responsible simply for
    drawing all of our game objects and more to the screen.
]]
function love.draw()
    -- begin drawing with push, in our virtual resolution
    push:start()

    love.graphics.clear(255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
    
    -- render different things depending on which part of the game we're in
    if gameState == 'start' then
        -- UI messages
        love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)
        love.graphics.printf('Welcome to Pong!', 0, 10, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.printf('Press Enter to begin!', 0, 20, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    elseif gameState == 'serve' then
        -- UI messages
        love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)
        love.graphics.printf('Player ' .. tostring(servingPlayer) .. "'s serve!", 
            0, 10, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.printf('Press Enter to serve!', 0, 20, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    elseif gameState == 'play' then
        -- no UI messages to display in play
    elseif gameState == 'done' then
        -- UI messages
        love.graphics.setFont(largeFont)
        love.graphics.printf('Player ' .. tostring(winningPlayer) .. ' wins!',
            0, 10, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
        love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)
        love.graphics.printf('Press Enter to restart!', 0, 30, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    end

    -- show the score before ball is rendered so it can move over the text
    displayScore()
    
    player1:render()
    player2:render()
    ball:render()

    -- display FPS for debugging; simply comment out to remove
    displayFPS()

    -- end our drawing to push
    push:finish()
end

--[[
    Simple function for rendering the scores.
]]
function displayScore()
    -- score display
    love.graphics.setFont(scoreFont)
    love.graphics.print(tostring(player1Score), VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - 50,
        VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 3)
    love.graphics.print(tostring(player2Score), VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 + 30,
        VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 3)
end

--[[
    Renders the current FPS.
]]
function displayFPS()
    -- simple FPS display across all states
    love.graphics.setFont(largeFont)
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 0/255, 0, 0/255)
    love.graphics.print('FPS: ' .. tostring(love.timer.getFPS()), 10, 10)
    love.graphics.setColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
end
```

Ball

```
Ball = Class{}

function Ball:init(x, y, width, height)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height

    -- these variables are for keeping track of our velocity on both the
    -- X and Y axis, since the ball can move in two dimensions
    self.dy = 0
    self.dx = 0
end

--[[
    Expects a paddle as an argument and returns true or false, depending
    on whether their rectangles overlap.
]]
function Ball:collides(paddle)
    -- first, check to see if the left edge of either is farther to the right
    -- than the right edge of the other
    if self.x > paddle.x + paddle.width or paddle.x > self.x + self.width then
        return false
    end

    -- then check to see if the bottom edge of either is higher than the top
    -- edge of the other
    if self.y > paddle.y + paddle.height or paddle.y > self.y + self.height then
        return false
    end 

    -- if the above aren't true, they're overlapping
    return true
end

--[[
    Places the ball in the middle of the screen, with no movement.
]]
function Ball:reset()
    self.x = VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - 2
    self.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 2
    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0
end

function Ball:update(dt)
    self.x = self.x + self.dx * dt
    self.y = self.y + self.dy * dt
end

function Ball:render()
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end
```

Paddle

```
Paddle = Class{}

function Paddle:init(x, y, width, height)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.dy = 0
end

function Paddle:update(dt)

    if self.dy < 0 then
        self.y = math.max(0, self.y + self.dy * dt)

    else
        self.y = math.min(VIRTUAL_HEIGHT - self.height, self.y + self.dy * dt)
    end
end


function Paddle:render()
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end
```

Push

```
local love11 = love.getVersion() == 11
local getDPI = love11 and love.window.getDPIScale or love.window.getPixelScale
local windowUpdateMode = love11 and love.window.updateMode or function(width, height, settings)
  local _, _, flags = love.window.getMode()
  for k, v in pairs(settings) do flags[k] = v end
  love.window.setMode(width, height, flags)
end

local push = {
  
  defaults = {
    fullscreen = false,
    resizable = false,
    pixelperfect = false,
    highdpi = true,
    canvas = true,
    stencil = true
  }
  
}
setmetatable(push, push)

function push:applySettings(settings)
  for k, v in pairs(settings) do
    self["_" .. k] = v
  end
end

function push:resetSettings() return self:applySettings(self.defaults) end

function push:setupScreen(WWIDTH, WHEIGHT, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT, settings)

  settings = settings or {}

  self._WWIDTH, self._WHEIGHT = WWIDTH, WHEIGHT
  self._RWIDTH, self._RHEIGHT = RWIDTH, RHEIGHT

  self:applySettings(self.defaults) --set defaults first
  self:applySettings(settings) --then fill with custom settings
  
  windowUpdateMode(self._RWIDTH, self._RHEIGHT, {
    fullscreen = self._fullscreen,
    resizable = self._resizable,
    highdpi = self._highdpi
  })

  self:initValues()

  if self._canvas then
    self:setupCanvas({ "default" }) --setup canvas
  end

  self._borderColor = {0, 0, 0}

  self._drawFunctions = {
    ["start"] = self.start,
    ["end"] = self.finish
  }

  return self
end

function push:setupCanvas(canvases)
  table.insert(canvases, { name = "_render", private = true }) --final render

  self._canvas = true
  self.canvases = {}

  for i = 1, #canvases do
    push:addCanvas(canvases[i])
  end

  return self
end
function push:addCanvas(params)
  table.insert(self.canvases, {
    name = params.name,
    private = params.private,
    shader = params.shader,
    canvas = love.graphics.newCanvas(self._WWIDTH, self._WHEIGHT),
    stencil = params.stencil or self._stencil
  })
end

function push:setCanvas(name)
  if not self._canvas then return true end
  local canvasTable = self:getCanvasTable(name)
  return love.graphics.setCanvas({ canvasTable.canvas, stencil = canvasTable.stencil })
end
function push:getCanvasTable(name)
  for i = 1, #self.canvases do
    if self.canvases[i].name == name then
      return self.canvases[i]
    end
  end
end
function push:setShader(name, shader)
  if not shader then
    self:getCanvasTable("_render").shader = name
  else
    self:getCanvasTable(name).shader = shader
  end
end

function push:initValues()
  self._PSCALE = (not love11 and self._highdpi) and getDPI() or 1
  
  self._SCALE = {
    x = self._RWIDTH/self._WWIDTH * self._PSCALE,
    y = self._RHEIGHT/self._WHEIGHT * self._PSCALE
  }
  
  if self._stretched then --if stretched, no need to apply offset
    self._OFFSET = {x = 0, y = 0}
  else
    local scale = math.min(self._SCALE.x, self._SCALE.y)
    if self._pixelperfect then scale = math.floor(scale) end
    
    self._OFFSET = {x = (self._SCALE.x - scale) * (self._WWIDTH/2), y = (self._SCALE.y - scale) * (self._WHEIGHT/2)}
    self._SCALE.x, self._SCALE.y = scale, scale --apply same scale to X and Y
  end
  
  self._GWIDTH = self._RWIDTH * self._PSCALE - self._OFFSET.x * 2
  self._GHEIGHT = self._RHEIGHT * self._PSCALE - self._OFFSET.y * 2
end

function push:apply(operation, shader)
  self._drawFunctions[operation](self, shader)
end

function push:start()
  if self._canvas then
    love.graphics.push()
    love.graphics.setCanvas({ self.canvases[1].canvas, stencil = self.canvases[1].stencil })

  else
    love.graphics.translate(self._OFFSET.x, self._OFFSET.y)
    love.graphics.setScissor(self._OFFSET.x, self._OFFSET.y, self._WWIDTH*self._SCALE.x, self._WHEIGHT*self._SCALE.y)
    love.graphics.push()
    love.graphics.scale(self._SCALE.x, self._SCALE.y)
  end
end

function push:applyShaders(canvas, shaders)
  local _shader = love.graphics.getShader()
  if #shaders <= 1 then
    love.graphics.setShader(shaders[1])
    love.graphics.draw(canvas)
  else
    local _canvas = love.graphics.getCanvas()

    local _tmp = self:getCanvasTable("_tmp")
    if not _tmp then --create temp canvas only if needed
      self:addCanvas({ name = "_tmp", private = true, shader = nil })
      _tmp = self:getCanvasTable("_tmp")
    end

    love.graphics.push()
    love.graphics.origin()
    local outputCanvas
    for i = 1, #shaders do
      local inputCanvas = i % 2 == 1 and canvas or _tmp.canvas
      outputCanvas = i % 2 == 0 and canvas or _tmp.canvas
      love.graphics.setCanvas(outputCanvas)
      love.graphics.clear()
      love.graphics.setShader(shaders[i])
      love.graphics.draw(inputCanvas)
      love.graphics.setCanvas(inputCanvas)
    end
    love.graphics.pop()

    love.graphics.setCanvas(_canvas)
    love.graphics.draw(outputCanvas)
  end
  love.graphics.setShader(_shader)
end

function push:finish(shader)
  love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(unpack(self._borderColor))
  if self._canvas then
    local _render = self:getCanvasTable("_render")

    love.graphics.pop()

    local white = love11 and 1 or 255
    love.graphics.setColor(white, white, white)

    --draw canvas
    love.graphics.setCanvas(_render.canvas)
    for i = 1, #self.canvases do --do not draw _render yet
      local _table = self.canvases[i]
      if not _table.private then
        local _canvas = _table.canvas
        local _shader = _table.shader
        self:applyShaders(_canvas, type(_shader) == "table" and _shader or { _shader })
      end
    end
    love.graphics.setCanvas()
    
    --draw render
    love.graphics.translate(self._OFFSET.x, self._OFFSET.y)
    local shader = shader or _render.shader
    love.graphics.push()
    love.graphics.scale(self._SCALE.x, self._SCALE.y)
    self:applyShaders(_render.canvas, type(shader) == "table" and shader or { shader })
    love.graphics.pop()

    --clear canvas
    for i = 1, #self.canvases do
      love.graphics.setCanvas(self.canvases[i].canvas)
      love.graphics.clear()
    end

    love.graphics.setCanvas()
    love.graphics.setShader()
  else
    love.graphics.pop()
    love.graphics.setScissor()
  end
end

function push:setBorderColor(color, g, b)
  self._borderColor = g and {color, g, b} or color
end

function push:toGame(x, y)
  x, y = x - self._OFFSET.x, y - self._OFFSET.y
  local normalX, normalY = x / self._GWIDTH, y / self._GHEIGHT
  
  x = (x >= 0 and x <= self._WWIDTH * self._SCALE.x) and normalX * self._WWIDTH or nil
  y = (y >= 0 and y <= self._WHEIGHT * self._SCALE.y) and normalY * self._WHEIGHT or nil
  
  return x, y
end

--doesn't work - TODO
function push:toReal(x, y)
  return x + self._OFFSET.x, y + self._OFFSET.y
end

function push:switchFullscreen(winw, winh)
  self._fullscreen = not self._fullscreen
  local windowWidth, windowHeight = love.window.getDesktopDimensions()
  
  if self._fullscreen then --save windowed dimensions for later
    self._WINWIDTH, self._WINHEIGHT = self._RWIDTH, self._RHEIGHT
  elseif not self._WINWIDTH or not self._WINHEIGHT then
    self._WINWIDTH, self._WINHEIGHT = windowWidth * .5, windowHeight * .5
  end
  
  self._RWIDTH = self._fullscreen and windowWidth or winw or self._WINWIDTH
  self._RHEIGHT = self._fullscreen and windowHeight or winh or self._WINHEIGHT
  
  self:initValues()
  
  love.window.setFullscreen(self._fullscreen, "desktop")
  if not self._fullscreen and (winw or winh) then
    windowUpdateMode(self._RWIDTH, self._RHEIGHT) --set window dimensions
  end
end

function push:resize(w, h)
  if self._highdpi then w, h = w / self._PSCALE, h / self._PSCALE end
  self._RWIDTH = w
  self._RHEIGHT = h
  self:initValues()
end

function push:getWidth() return self._WWIDTH end
function push:getHeight() return self._WHEIGHT end
function push:getDimensions() return self._WWIDTH, self._WHEIGHT end

return push
```

Everything else can be gotten on the internet. Just delete the sound flies so the code can run. It will be very helpful to get this working.

Comment: please understand that it is very unlikely someone will actually read through all your code. you should learn to focus. reduce your code to a [mcve]. Don't ask us to remove things so your code will run. remove it for us. how is sound related to a border anyway? it is not even clear what you mean with border around your game. please read [ask] and improve your post

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to code this but I have had a situation similar and this may work. This is where you limit the movement of the ball by saying something along the lines of
if(ball_x > 10 or ball_x < 0)then
ball_x_momentum = - ball_x_momentum
end
where the constants are the bounds of the box. Then repeat the code for the y direction. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

oh wow that's a lot of code.

assuming that you need the ball to bounce off the top and bottom of the window (if you need it to bounce off the side of the window, try changing `self.y` to `self.x` and `love.graphics.getHeight` to `love.graphics.getWidth`)

try adding:

```
if self.y < 0 then -- if the ball is touching the top of the screen
    self.y = 0
    self.dy = math.abs(self.dy)
end
```

and also add:

```
if self.y > love.graphics.getHeight() then -- if the ball is touching the bottom of the screen
    self.y = love.graphics.getHeight()
    self.dy = math.abs(self.dy)
end
```

this code should go to the `ball.lua` file, in `Ball:update(dt)`

hopefully this helps.